# Correct cmake version not detected, unable to install ANTs

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, ant, windows-10, cmake-gui

I am running a git code in Jupyter, in Conda on my Windows 10 machine.

This has a ANTs dependency. I followed [this](https://github.com/ANTsX/ANTs/wiki/Compiling-ANTs-on-Linux-and-Mac-OS#get-the-latest-code) tutorial.

on which I realized ANTs needs a cmake version of 3.10 or higher.

On my Ubuntu WSL on my Windows 10, I have installed cmake version 3.14.0-rc1 following instructions [here](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/755/install-upgrade-cmake-3.10.1-ubuntu-14.04-trusty-alternatives#.XHeb8IgzaUk). What is rc1? Is that causing the problem? I did not find any non-rc1 in [here](http://www.cmake.org/files)

```
LAB-005:~/bin/ants/cmake-3.14.0-rc1$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.14.0-rc1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
LAB-005:
```

So looks like cmake is good.

I go back to this bit

```
cd ~/bin/ants
ccmake ~/code/ANTs
```

and when I hit c on this screen, [image]

I see this:
[image]

I'm frustrated. Spent too much time on this uninstalling, reinstalling. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed it.

I tried running cmake gui and it did not work.

My cmake and ccmake versions were different like so:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.14.0-rc1
$ ccmake --version
ccmake version 3.5.1
```

1. Uninstall cmake

```
sudo make uninstall
```

2. Check

```
cmake --version
ccmake --version
which cmake
which ccmake
```

3. Download binary 3.13.4

```
wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.13/cmake-3.13.4.tar.gz
```

4.Unzip

```
tar -xvzf cmake-3.13.4.tar.gz
```

5. Enter unzipped directory

```
cd cmake-3.13.4/
```

6. Configure

```
./configure
```

7. Install something called checkinstall (only this method worked for me)

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

8. Run it

```
sudo checkinstall
```

9. Check

```
$ which cmake ccmake & cmake --version && ccmake --version
/usr/local/bin/cmake
/usr/local/bin/ccmake
cmake version 3.13.4
ccmake version 3.13.4
```

10. Go back to ANTs installation

    ccmake ~/code/ANTs
    (hit c)